# Filter rows by those created within a close timeframe

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a application where users create orders that are stored in a Oracle database. I'm trying to find a bug that only happens when a user creates orders within 30 seconds of the last order they created.

Here is the structure of the order table:

```
order_id | user_id | creation_date
```

I would like to write a query that can give me a list of orders where the creation_date is within 30 seconds of the last order for the same user. The results will hopefully help me find the bug.

I tried using the Oracle LAG() function but it doesn't seem to with the WHERE clause.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT O.*
FROM YourTable O
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM YourTable O2
   WHERE
      O.creation_date > O2.creation_date
      AND O.user_id = O2.user_id
      AND O.creation_date - (30 / 86400) <= O2.creation_date
);
```

See this in action [in a Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9133/3).

You can use the `LAG` function if you want, you would just have to wrap the query into a derived table and then put your `WHERE` condition in the outer query.

Comment: What about `for the same user` requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct
  t1.order_id, t1.user_id, t1.creation_date
FROM 
  YourTable t1
  join YourTable t2 
    on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
    and t2.creation_date between t1.creation_date - 30/86400 and t1.creation_date
    and t2.rowid <> t1.rowid
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: This will return every order in the system.

Comment: @ErikE - why do you think so?

Comment: I don't just think it. I **know it**. [Here's proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c336/2).

Answer (score 0):

Example of using LAG():

```
SELECT id, (pss - css) time_diff_in_seconds
      , creation_date, prev_date
  FROM
  (
  SELECT id, creation_date, prev_date
       , EXTRACT(SECOND From creation_date) css
       , EXTRACT(SECOND From prev_date) pss 
    FROM
    (
    SELECT id, creation_date
         , LAG(creation_date, 1, creation_date) OVER (ORDER BY creation_date) prev_date
     FROM
     ( -- Table/data --
      SELECT 1 id, timestamp '2013-03-20 13:56:58' creation_date FROM dual
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, timestamp '2013-03-20 13:57:27' FROM dual
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, timestamp '2013-03-20 13:59:16' FROM dual
     )))
 --WHERE (pss - css) <= 30
/

ID    TIME_DIFF_IN_SECONDS
--------------------------
1       0     <<-- if uncomment where
2       31   
3       11    <<-- if uncomment where
```

Comment: Don't you mean `pss - css <= 30`?

Comment: @Erik - yep, you are correct and read my mind. :) Thank you very much.